# WPF UserControl validation problem

Tags: wpf, validation

I have `UserControl` bounded to my view model. View model implements `IDataErrorInfo`. `UserConrol` has `Validation.ErrorTemplate`. In this template I use converter to show tooltip with errors:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner">
                            <Image x:Name="imgError"
                                       Width="32"
                                       Height="32"
                                       Margin="5"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors),Converter={StaticResource ValidationErrors2TooltipConverter},ConverterParameter='Couldn't save hour work:'}"
                                       Source="{StaticResource ErrorDrawingImage}" />
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

When I change some property (for instance: `ComboBox`'s selection), the number of error should change, but it doesn't. I couldn't find a way to refresh errors in `ToolTip`.

**Questions:**

1. How could I refresh errors in `ToolTip`.
2. Validation works fine for `UserControl`, but doesn't work for components inside it. I defined `Validation.ErrorTemplate`'s for components in `UserControl`, but they are not visible, however controls bounded to view models (with `IDataErrorInfo`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation pattern must be applied for each control inside your UserControl. There's no "inheritance".

Comment: So I need to create own view model for each control, which implements `IDataErrorInfo`? May be it would solve second issue, but what about first?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Comment: I don't think you have to create several models, but the ValidationError is defined for each control.

Comment: The refresh issue could derive because you are binding the whole collection of errors, instead the single error item. Perhaps the collection does not expose any notification on its changes.

Comment: The type of collection is `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>`